# A letter from Mr. Pirate, Mr. Roller, and Mr. Knight

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, grid-deduction, crosswords, mazes

<sub>Though I don't think it will help, you may check with the beginning of my story concerning [Red Herring Puzzle Club](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67478/r-h-p-c-crossword-puzzle).</sub>

It seems like it's been a long time since I tried to enter the R.H.P.C. As you may know, I lost a lot of reputation to find someone able to solve it, and moreover, when I was finally ready to give the answer, the bar I had visited had already been abandoned.

Yet I continued looking for any traces of Red Herring Puzzle Club. After a lot of snooping and sneaking all around the world, I found the bartender who gave me the puzzle in the first place.

-- Oh, Thomas, long time no see. Looks like you're a bit lost. But fear not, because today three suspicious people came to me and warned, that you might come by.

With these words he handed me an envelope.

[image: this very envelope, shot later]

-- I assure you, my friend, that inside you will find all the answers you will ever need. -- the bartender grinned.

After coming home (I already knew, I was never going to see this man again) I opened the envelope. There were 7 small sheets of paper inside. I have also discovered some diagrams on the outside of the envelope. Here is all of what I have got:

[image: simpler squares]

[image: more complex squares]

[image: whatever]

But, unlike the previous puzzle, this looks like nothing familiar. I don't know where to start at all! At least, I have unlimited time now, so I can wait for help all I want :D What is the mysterious message, hidden within these papers?

---

I should probably apply the transcript of two most informative squares:

piece 6, one way around:

> Tight (4) 
>  
>   Lincoln (3) 
>   Speeded (4) 
>   ??? (word was smudged beyond recognition) (5) 
>   Twinkle (4) 
>   Panda (2) God (4) 
>   Twins (5)

piece 6, other way around:

> Destroy (4) 
>   Greenpeace (4)
>   Cupid (4)
>   Abbacy (7)
>   Superior (4)
>   Circle (3) Thus (2)
>   Number (2)

piece 4

> up(?): 
>   I will let your door be spun (5)
>   I'm a letter, not the start, (5)
>   I'm a smell that you should ban (4)
>   right(?):
>   I'm with ocean in part one (6)
>   I'm before you'd say in Rome (4)
>   Canoeic palindrome, alas, (5)
>   down(?):
>   I'm three less, if upside down (4)
>   I can swirl, flow, stick and foam (4)
>   And one of three who might be us (6)
>   left(?):
>   I'm a distance you can run (7)
>   I am therefore from Descartes (4)
>   I pay taxes to no man (6)

---

As stated by OmegaCrypton, it's hard to distinguish green colour in the photos. Here is the 7th piece with all black numbers circled:

[image: green ink]

It looks like the same green ink was used on the cover, for the ticks and for a single dot.

---

A hint (a week has passed, 2 answers submitted)

> [image: a very small hint shall i say hahahahahahaha]

---

A correction I couldn't have made due to the puzzle being on paper:

1) The "ABBACY" hint should technically be "ABBEY" (though I believe these words mean pretty much the same)

2) The "before you say in Rome" hint is completely false; not only I meant 'after', this word doesn't seem to mean even that (yeah); nevertheless, I'm not going to reveal it.

---

A special hint (on jafe's progress):

> Uif qjsbuf't dbmnmz xbjujoh,
> ijt mfht tujmm cfjoh cpvoe:
> Ipx dbo if tubsu, opu lopxjoh
> Xibu tmjuifst jo uif hspvoe.
> Znk qtomnz oy grsuyz xkgje,
> Yusk rkzzkxy soyyotm - ckrr,
> Oz tkbkx sgzzkxkj cngz znke ckxk,
> Haz xgznkx cnkxk znke lkrr.
> Sgd qnkkdq'r, sgntfg, hm ozmhb:
> Ghr qgxldr vdqd zkk hfmnqdc:
> Mnv gd hr bqnrrdc: gd vzmsdc
> Vnqcr sn fn vnqc ax vnqc.

---

A brand new hint-pack for you:

> [image: those three are together on purpose]

Comment: nice puzzle, +1! however, the difference in ink for piece 7 is not clearly seen. can you send a clearer image of it please? thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Anything that I can help you with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pirate

> Piece 7 makes a nonogram when the numbers are moved outside of the grid. This has two possible solutions (either A or B cells are black).
>  [image]
>
>  In the top left corner of the envelope, there's a hint that black means 3, white means 2 and green means 1. These numbers form a slitherlink puzzle.
>  [image]
>
>  Piece 5 appears to have a part of the loop already filled in. However, this doesn't fit the numbers as is, which is where I got stuck. However, LeppyR64 figured out how to fit everything together: turn piece 5 90 degrees clockwise.
>  [image]
>
>  Looking at the pictures, the pirate cannot cross the slitherlink and only takes letters on which he steps with his good leg. So let's pick every second square only:
>  [image]
>
>  Taking the corresponding letters from piece 1 gives **QGOBMDUDQDW**.
>  [image]

The roller

> The clues from piece 4 match the crossword on piece 2. The answers form a word chain that goes clockwise from the top-left corner.
>
>  I'm a distance you can run (7) = STRETCH
>  I will let your door be spun (5) = HINGE
>  I'm with ocean in part one (6) = ELEVEN
>  I'm three less, if upside down (4) = NINE
>  I am therefore from Descartes (4) = ERGO
>  I'm a letter, not the start, (5) = OMEGA
>  I'm before you'd say in Rome (4) = ANNO (this was given in a hint)
>  I can swirl, flow, stick and foam (4) = OOZE
>  I pay taxes to no man (6) = EVADER
>  I'm a smell that you should ban (4) = REEK
>  Canoeic palindrome, alas, (5) = KAYAK
>  And one of three who might be us (6) = KNIGHT
>
>  [image]
>
>  Piece 1 shows the start and end points of the maze. It looks from the pictures that the roller goes straight until he hits a wall or an E, and he cannot pass through squares with an O. (Thanks to LeppyR64 for figuring out the correct path here.)
>  [image]
>
>  Back to piece 1. Taking the letters on the squares where the roller hits a wall, we get **QABMLLWJCOW**.
>  [image]

The knight

> The clues from piece 6 fit the crossword on piece 3. Right-side-up clues go **across**, topmost first:
>  Tight (4) = ROPE
>  Lincoln (3) = ABE
>  Speeded (4) = SPED
>  ??? (5) = SWEAR
>  Twinkle (4) = STAR
>  Panda (2) God (4) = [PO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Po_(Kung_Fu_Panda)) / LOKI
>  Twins (5) = OLSEN<sup>1</sup>
>
>  Upside-down clues go **down**, rightmost first:
>  Destroy (4) = RUIN
>  Greenpeace (4) = PETA
>  Cupid (4) = EROS
>  Abbacy (7) = REDWALL<sup>1</sup>
>  Superior (4) = BEST
>  Circle (3) Thus (2) = LAP / SO
>  Number (2) = PI
>  <sub><sup>1</sup> Found by M Oehm in the comments.</sub>
>
>  [image]
>  Again, piece 1 displays the start and end squares of the maze. This one is solved by making chess-style **knight** moves on the free squares. (OP acknowledged in the comments that the final square was blocked by accident.)
>  [image]
>
>  Taking the visited letters from piece 1 gives us **QQAWPLDPALW**.
>  [image]

Putting everything together

> So the final clue is `11+? 11+? 11+? = 33`. We have the 11-letter sequences QGOBMDUDQDW, QABMLLWJCOW and QQAWPLDPALW. By rotating letters by a number of positions we get:
>
>  QGOBMDUDQDW, rotate by 1 -> RHPCNEVEREX
>  QABMLLWJCOW, rotate by 18 -> ISTEDDOBUGO
>  QQAWPLDPALW, rotate by 15 -> FFPLEASEPAL

So the solution is

> **RHPC NEVER EXISTED. DO BUG OFF PLEASE, PAL.** Which must be disappointing for our hero.

Comment: Good work! Regarding Piece 6: [twins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary-Kate_and_Ashley_Olsen); [abbey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redwall); [Greenpeace](https://www.shipsnostalgia.com/gallery/showphoto.php/photo/329561/title/vega28greenpeace-iii-29/cat/518) (not quite sure here; it will leave an unclues two-letter word)

Comment: @MOehm Nice finds, thanks! These fill in the middle row plausibly as well.

Comment: @MOehm Sorry about unclued "ke"; I must assure you it's the only unclued word there were to be.

Comment: Pretty sure slither means slitherlink, but I can't go further than that. As it turns out, I'm bad at those

Comment: @jafe (1) The knight's almost done, I should just mention that "VEGA" is not what I had in mind; I was thinking of a similarly popular faunal group. Also I messed up a little blocking the exit, but you'll get over it. (2) I will give hint on the Pirate later today. (3!) You either get a hint on the roman word I messed up, either on the overall puzzle structure. I'll post once you make a choice >:)

Comment: @ThomasBlue The Roman word, please. I think we can still figure out the structure eventually...

Comment: @jafe Good. The first one has exactly one word wrong, though, allowing a way too short. The third one uses the nonogram, though, so you stepped off the right way. See the markers in the corner.

Comment: @ThomasBlue Ah, now I see it. Thanks!

Comment: I think you have the solution but you need to change your "perspective" on the Nonogram/Slitherlink

Comment: What was the method to make the maze in The Roller?

Comment: I simply marked all E's and O's as walls. That part is still wrong, though...

Comment: And you haven't used the letters on Piece 1 yet, correct?

Comment: @LeppyR64 Yeah, those haven't been used anywhere yet.

Comment: @jafe The word "rank" is not the intented word. As for everything else, you're good. You should already have 3 same-length letter sequences. The last step is just repeating what you already did once.

Comment: @jafe You already got 2/3 correct. I confirm that it is REEK, "ban" was just for the sake of rhyming.

Comment: @ThomasBlue Aaa, I didn't even realize the rhyme since I've been reading them in the wrong order... Very nice!

Comment: @jafe Once again, you should just get back to what you've already tried. The problem was only with the word, not the method ;)

Comment: @jafe, You can get closer to a correct answer if you forbid hitting o's, as shown on the envelope. And even without it, you have one extra step.

Comment: When you reach the N in anno... go left instead of right.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Thanks! That has to be it...

Answer (score 5):

some clues to get the ball rolling...

### piece 4

up(?):

```
I will let your door be spun (5)
```

> pivot

```
I'm a letter, not the start, (5)
```

> omega

```
I'm a smell that you should ban (4)
```

right(?):

```
I'm with ocean in part one (6)
I'm before you'd say in Rome (4)
Canoeic palindrome, alas, (5)
```

> tanka, meaning = oceanic, anagram of (canoeic)

down(?):

```
I'm three less, if upside down (4)
```

> five / nine (thanks @Penguino!)

```
I can swirl, flow, stick and foam (4)
And one of three who might be us (6)
```

> myself

left(?):

```
I'm a distance you can run (7)
```

> yardage/ [furlong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furlong)?

```
I am therefore from Descartes (4)
```

> ergo

```
I pay taxes to no man (6)
```

---

### piece 6, one way around:

```
Tight (4)
```

> hard

```
Lincoln (3)
```

> abe

```
Speeded (4)
```

> sped

```
??? (word was smudged beyond recognition) (5)
Twinkle (4)
Panda (2) God (4)
```

> ?, zeus?

```
Twins (5)
```

### piece 6, other way around:

```
Destroy (4)
```

> ruin

```
Greenpeace (4)
```

> ecol

```
Cupid (4)
```

> love

```
Abbacy (7)
Superior (4)
```

> only/ over

```
Circle (3) Thus (2)
```

> ?, so

```
Number (2)
```

> no

---

### A special hint (partial)

1st step:

> decode it with rot 1 to get
> The pirate's calmly waiting,
> his legs still being bound:
> How can he start, not knowing
> What slithers in the ground.
> Ymj psnlmy nx fqrtxy wjfid,
> Xtrj qjyyjwx rnxxnsl - bjqq,
> Ny sjajw rfyyjwji bmfy ymjd bjwj,
> Gzy wfymjw bmjwj ymjd kjqq.
> Rfc pmjjcp'q, rfmsef, gl nylga:
> Fgq pfwkcq ucpc yjj gelmpcb:
> Lmu fc gq apmqqcb: fc uylrcb
> Umpbq rm em umpb zw umpb.

Comment: can anyone please explain the downvote? i welcome any constructive feedback, thanks in advance :)

Comment: I've downvoted because this isn't really a "partial answer" -- you've given guesses on *a few* of the clues in *one part* of this much bigger puzzle, but there's no part of the puzzle solved here. There's not even any confirmation that these answers are correct, making what little you *do* have seem baseless. This seems more like comment material (if that).

Comment: @Deusovi i hope this is more than a few... thanks! :)

Comment: I think "I'm three less, if upside down (4)" might be 'nine'. as in 6 = 9 - 3

Answer (score 3):

Merging of Piece 5 and Piece 7 from @jafe's answer:

> Piece 5 and Piece 7 were 90 degrees different in rotation (Red crib row)
>  [image]

Comment: Nice work! I notice the way out takes 22 steps, and the envelope seems to call for 11 letters from each... Maybe the pirate, having one wooden leg, only picks every second letter?

Answer (score 3):

Jafe's hint:

> Uif qjsbuf't dbmnmz xbjujoh,
>   ijt mfht tujmm cfjoh cpvoe:
>   Ipx dbo if tubsu, opu lopxjoh
>   Xibu tmjuifst jo uif hspvoe.
>
> Znk qtomnz oy grsuyz xkgje,
>   Yusk rkzzkxy soyyotm - ckrr,
>   Oz tkbkx sgzzkxkj cngz znke ckxk,
>   Haz xgznkx cnkxk znke lkrr.
>
> Sgd qnkkdq'r, sgntfg, hm ozmhb:
>   Ghr qgxldr vdqd zkk hfmnqdc:
>   Mnv gd hr bqnrrdc: gd vzmsdc
>   Vnqcr sn fn vnqc ax vnqc.

becomes:

> ROT25
>  The pirate's calmly waiting,
>  his legs still being bound:
>  How can he start, not knowing
>  What slithers in the ground.
>
>  ROT20
>  The knight is almost ready,
>  Some letters missing - well,
>  It never mattered what they were,
>  But rather where they fell.
>
>  ROT1
>  The roller's, though, in panic:
>  His rhymes were all ignored:
>  Now he is crossed: he wanted
>  Words to go word by word.